# Mapping two foreign keys to one primary key (XML Mapping)

Tags: nhibernate, orm

I've searched a lot after a solution for this, but the only thing that came out was a solution with FH-mapping instead of XML-mappng.
I'm working with a QR-scanning system where two users can scan eachother. If one user shoots an other user their id got filled in in this table.
So the two FK's will be unique together. 1-2. 2-1, 1-3
So my domain actually contains this two classes:

```
public class SnappedUsers
{
    public virtual User Shooter {get; set;}
    public virtual User Target { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime SnapDate { get; set; }
}
public class User : Entity
{
    public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public virtual string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProfilePicUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual int Money { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
}
```

The table SnappedUsers should contain two foreign keys from the User table.
(it's not necessary that i put an Shooter ISet and an Target ISet to my User class.)
How do i actually have to map these things with XML-mapping? I don't see a solution myself for now.

Thx in advance

Comment: you can't basicly, because message has nothing unique and NHibernate needs some kind of Identity if it is not a component.

Comment: @Firo Okay, thx for your reply. You're right, their is nothing unique indeed. The message example was actually an example to give a better explanation. My real world application is about scanning each others QR code. If you (id = 1) and I (id = 2) register we both get a QR code. When I scan yours or id's will be added to this table as foreign key. When you scan me you are the shooter and i'm the target. So our two keys together are unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<composite-id> 
  <key-many-to-one name="Shooter" column="shooter_Id" >
  <key-many-to-one name="Target" column="target_Id" />
</composite-id>
```

Comment: Yesterday someone said me the same but adviced me to use an extra unique id instead. What's your opinion about this?

Comment: it would make it easier to have more than one SnappedUsers with the same references and it doesnt hurt

Comment: Yeah that's true. But it's not the intention to snap one user multiple times.